# Less/more than equal gas cost

Tags: contract-development, tokens, contract-deployment, gas, optimization

i've read on a blog that it is most costly gas wise to write eg. x <= y than x < y + 1, do you have any ideea if it's true and why would that be the case? Except that blog I couldn't find anything else stating this.
This is the blog in question:https://nftchance.medium.com/the-gas-efficient-way-of-building-and-launching-an-erc721-nft-project-for-2022-b3b1dac5f2e1

Comment: If you are doing those micro optimizations I'd you are doing something wrong. If you are serious about gas then write directly in assembly. Arithmetic operations in the EVM are very cheap I'd look for optimizing the more expensive operations first, like storage and memory allocations.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to study the Ethereum Yellow Paper. All operations in the following set have the same gas cost.

```
Wverylow = {ADD, SUB, NOT, LT, GT, SLT, SGT, EQ, ISZERO, AND, OR, XOR, BYTE, SHL, SHR, SAR,
CALLDATALOAD, MLOAD, MSTORE, MSTORE8, PUSH*, DUP*, SWAP*}
```

To evaluate which of the statements this question refers to is more gas efficient, one would have to understand how the statements are translated into assembly code.

A more practical way to find out which of the statements is better could be, for example, the use of:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#estimategas